# How to change Android Studio Flutter comment color

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I know how to change default color of usual comment

but sometimes I can see the text color with []

[this text has a color]

Answer (score 0):

That's Dart way of showing that the text within the brackets are source code text and can have different color. It's in monospace font. It's the same as using `<code>this is source text</code>`.

Under `Documentation comment` (the comment starting with `///`) (equivalent to JavaDoc comment), but there is no way to change the color.

```
/// The method [buildForm] blah blah
```

is the same as

```
/// The method <code>buildForm</code> blah blah
```

Comment: what do you mean of <code>this is source text</code>?

Comment: See my updates above.